# attaching to android native app with gdb closes app on device

Tags: android, gdb, android-ndk

I am attempting to debug my native app compiled with ndk-r6. When I attempt to run ndk-gdb to attach the debugger to the process, the app quits on the device. I am stumped. Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

Here is a log of a run of the gdb process: http://pastebin.com/qTCR7mF2

This is all I get out of logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(10006): Process com.gmail.whittock.tom.clockwork (pid 11460) has died.
I/WindowManager(10006): WIN DEATH: Window{4083aa18 com.gmail.whittock.tom.clockwork/com.gmail.whittock.tom.Util.NativeActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(10006): WIN DEATH: Window{4085d8d0 SurfaceView paused=false}
I/WindowManager(10006): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(10006): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=234/10 loc=en_GB touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=31 themeResource=null}
```

EDIT:

and this is my gdb.setup file:

```
$ cat libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
set solib-search-path C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/Clockwork/obj/local/armeabi-v7a
directory C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/ANDROI~2/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/ANDROI~2/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/ANDROI~2/sources/cxx-stl/system/include C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/modules/box2d C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/Clockwork/jni
```

all paths in there look correct to me, but perhaps it's the use of the dos-compatibility versions of filenames that's causing the issue?!

EDIT2: This is the *other* gdb.setup file:

```
$ cat obj/local/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup 
file C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/Clockwork/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
target remote :5039
file C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/Clockwork/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
target remote :5039
file C:/Users/Tom/dev/android/Clockwork/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
target remote :5039
```

Comment: Could you please show us your gdb.setup file? The linked log says there's something wrong with a command there.

Comment: It's a Desire HD device, rooted.

Comment: I'm with molnarm -- looks like something's wrong with your GDB setup and the log indicates it is killing your process intentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

ndk-gdb HAS HAS HAS to have `NDK_DEBUG=1` environment variable set, otherwise the NDK_APP_GDBSETUP variable gets set to blank due to make believing that the app isn't debuggable (being too damn smart for its own good)

This then causes the gdb.setup file to get corrupted, because a copy command fails and we start appending to the end of anything that is already there. This is why the same command pair is repeated 3 times in obj/local.../gdb.setup.

You have no idea how much pain this has caused me. Hopefully someone else will have an easier time if they read this.

Answer (score 0):

[Step by step instructions to setting up GDB on eclipse](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/) Your GDB configuration is probably borked. Rather than trying to diagnose the problem, try following those steps and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: thanks. I'm not running eclipse, and the third step. i have already performed the first three steps which apply to my situation.